# Operator overload problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

In person.h, under the public section of a class named person, I have this:

```
bool operator < (person& currentPerson);
```

In person.cpp I have this:

```
bool person::operator < (person& currentPerson)
{
   return age < currentPerson.age;
}
```

When I compile it I get a linker error, but only if I actually use the operator.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the error message.

```
1>FunctionTemplates.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall person::operator<(class person const &)" (??Mperson@@QAE_NABV0@@Z) referenced in function "class person __cdecl max(class person &,class person &)" (?max@@YA?AVperson@@AAV1@0@Z)
1>c:\users\kenneth\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\FunctionTemplates\Debug\FunctionTemplates.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Comment: How are you using the operator and what is the type of the `person` (right operand) object you're using with it?

Comment: try to update the signature with `const`, to `bool operator < (const person& currentPerson);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, when using function `max`, You are comparing a person with a temporary person. For that to work you need to take const reference.

```
bool operator < (const person& currentPerson)  const;
                 ^^^^                          ^^^^^^ //This wont hurt too
```

and

```
bool person::operator < (const person& currentPerson)
//                       ^^^^^
{
   return age < currentPerson.age;
}
```

Comment: What makes the person temporary? Neither of the person objects are constants.

Comment: You are not declaring them as constants. But sometimes STL algorithms create temporaries. For example `p < person(1)` will not work unless the operator function accepts a const reference.

Comment: This fixes it by the way, I would just like more information on why what I originally had was wrong

Comment: @kennycoc The reason `p < person(1)` wont work is because you can not take a reference of  the temporary `person(1)` which really doesn't have an address and is created on the fly. The compiler needs to know that you don't intend to modify it to allow you to do that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll definitely have to do more research on when functions need `const` paramaters

Comment: @kennycoc Glad it helped. And you should.